# send email to a specific Lotus Notes contacts using VBA

Tags: vba, email, excel, lotus-notes

I have 'column A' with different names. I have all this people email contacts in my lotus notes account. I want to send an email to multiple recipients (to the people including in column A). I mean:

```
    column A:        
    Ludvig Simpson        
    Matthew Ricky        
    Anne Cameron  
    etc...
```

And for example Ludvig Simpson has this lotus email address: dbyw4680, Matthew Ricky has cjua321 and  Anne Cameron has ofdb1621. All this email addresses are found only in my lotus account.

My question: How can I send an email to Ludvig, Matthew and Anne??(I mean how to take automatically their address email from lotus?). To specify, the names in 'column A' are the same with the names in my lotus account.

I don't want to put their email addresses in a range/column one by one because the people name list is dinamic, changes, can grows.

Have you any idea?

Here is my code that send message to a multiple recipient taken from column A:

```
    Sub sendEmail()        
    Dim noSession As Object, noDatabase As Object, noDocument As Object
    Dim obAttachment As Object, EmbedObject As Object
    Dim stSubject As Variant, stAttachment As String
    Dim vaRecipient As Variant
    Dim vaMsg As Variant

    Const EMBED_ATTACHMENT As Long = 1454
    Const stTitle As String = "Status Active workbook"
    Const stMsg As String = "The active workbook must first be saved " & vbCrLf _
     & "before it can be sent as an attachment."

   'If the active workbook has not been saved at all.
    If Len(ActiveWorkbook.Path) = 0 Then
        MsgBox stMsg, vbInformation, stTitle
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim x As Integer
    For x = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        'Get the name of the recipient from the user.
        vaRecipient = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & x).Value

    Do 'Get the message from the user.
           vaMsg = "My email text"
    Loop While vaMsg = ""
    If vaMsg = False Then Exit Sub   'If the user has canceled the operation.

    'Add the subject to the outgoing e-mail which also can be retrieved from the users
    'in a similar way as above.
     stSubject = "My subject email"

    'Retrieve the path and filename of the active workbook.
     stAttachment = ActiveWorkbook.FullName

    'Instantiate the Lotus Notes COM's Objects.
     Set noSession = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
     Set noDatabase = noSession.GETDATABASE("", "")

     'If Lotus Notes is not open then open the mail-part of it.
      On Error Resume Next
      If noDatabase.IsOpen = False Then noDatabase.OPENMAIL

    'Create the e-mail
     Set noDocument = noDatabase.CreateDocument

    'Add values to the created e-mail main properties.
     With noDocument
        .Form = "Memo"
        .sendto = vaRecipient
        .Subject = stSubject
        .Body = vaMsg
        .SaveMessageOnSend = True
     End With

    'Send the e-mail.
     Dim myMessage As String
     myMessage = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to send the email?", vbYesNo, "Are you sure?")

     If myMessage = vbYes Then
         With noDocument
             .PostedDate = Now()
             .SEND 0, vaRecipient
         End With
    'Release objects from the memory.
    Set EmbedObject = Nothing
    Set obAttachment = Nothing
    Set noDocument = Nothing
    Set noDatabase = Nothing
    Set noSession = Nothing

       'Activate Excel for the user.
       AppActivate "Microsoft Excel"

          MsgBox "The e-mail has successfully been created and distributed.", vbInformation, "Done!"
      Else
       MsgBox "Unsent email!", vbInformation, "Unsent email"
      End If
     Next x
  End Sub
```

Comment: There are samples on [Ron de Bruin - XL Dennis](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/notes/notes3.htm) that show you how to retrive the email addresses from Lotus Notes.

Comment: also, doesn't Lotus Notes resolve the account names into their respective email addresses in much the same way that MS Exchange does?

Comment: Philip: thanks for the link. I don't know many things about MS Exchange

Comment: well, surely Lotus Notes mail object has a method to resolve account names into addresses?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am a beginner with Lotus Notes. I started using it few weeks ago.

Comment: Yes, Notes easily resolves user names -- as long as what you have in the spreadsheet matches one of the appropriate fields in the Domnino Directory. (E.g., FullName, ShortName, InternetAddress, and even in some configurations FirstName or LastName as long as they are unique in the directory).

Comment: @Richard Schwartz: I thought I can retrieve name email address if I have the appropriate field but I don't know how. Philip gave me a link but that code has errors.

Comment: @musiclandia your best bet is to try out the code from Ron de Bruin's site, the ask another question for help with fixing any errors or improving it. As Richared says, you should be able to resolve the user names by calling the appropriate method on the Lotus Notes object connected to the Domino (server) instance.

Comment: also, a Google search threw up some more resources for you: [BigResource-Visual-Basic-to-send-Lotus-Notes-Email](http://www.bigresource.com/VB-Visual-Basic-to-send-Lotus-Notes-Email-039-s-to-multiple-recipients--qQPm7FnXjQ.html) and [IBM: How to send Lotus Notes mail messages with Microsoft Visual Basic](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21178583) and

Comment: You can search for addresses from the $People view in Names.nsf.  I actually haven't done that from VBA, but in LotusScript that's the way you do it.  BTW, depending on how the administrator has the server configured, it (the server) may be quite generous in matching.  For example, john_smith@acme.com would receive mail addresses to john@acme.com or smith@acme.com, or jsmith@acme.com, assuming that those are all unique.