# Create excel mail merge with IBM Notes

Tags: excel, vba, lotus-notes, mailmerge

Good Morning,

I have some code that will create an email mailmerge in IBM Notes based on columns in excel.  Only trouble I am running into is I would like to create separate emails for each email address in column A.  I also cannot figure out how to have it attach a specific file for each recipient, the location of the files would be in column C.  Can anyone help me out?

```
Sub SendQuoteToEmail()

 Dim NSession As Object
 Dim NDatabase As Object
 Dim NUIWorkSpace As Object
 Dim NDoc As Object
 Dim NUIdoc As Object
 Dim WordApp As Object
 Dim subject As String
 Dim EmailAddress As Variant

 subject = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2")
 Debug.Print subject

Set NSession = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
Set NUIWorkSpace = CreateObject("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace")
Set NDatabase = NSession.GetDatabase("", "")
If Not NDatabase.IsOpen Then NDatabase.OPENMAIL

 For all Emai-Addresses
EmailAddress =                        Worksheets("Sheet1").Application.Transpose(Range("A2").Resize(Range("A" &                           Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value)
Set NDoc = NDatabase.CreateDocument

With NDoc
    .Form = "Memo" ' or .ReplaceItemValue("Form", "Memo")
    .SendTo = EmailAddress
    .subject = subject
End With
Set rtitem = NDoc.CreateRichTextItem("Body")
Call rt.AppendText(Worksheets("sheet1").Range("d2") & vbLf & vbLf)
Call rt.EmbedObject(1454, "", "c:filepath.doc")
Call NDoc.Save(True, False)
Next ' email-address
Set NDoc = NDatabase.CreateDocument

 With NDoc
.SendTo = EmailAddress
'.CopyTo = ""
.subject = subject

.body = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("d2") & vbLf & vbLf


.Save True, False
 End With

Set NUIdoc = NUIWorkSpace.EDITDocument(True, NDoc)
With NUIdoc

Set WordApp = Nothing
End With

Set NSession = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To attach files, look at the EmbedObject method of the NotesRichTextItem class.

There are also a couple of other issues with your code.
You should not use extended notation when you assign values to fields, use the ReplaceItemValue methor of the NotesDocument class to store values.
The *Body* field is a rich text field and you should use the NotesRichTextItem class for anything related to that field, hence use the Appendtext and AddNewLine methods to write the content into the field. That would also allow you to use the EmbeddObject method I mention above to attach files.

You can perhaps find some useful hints in my mail notification class. I just posted an updated version at 
http://blog.texasswede.com/updated-mailnotification-class-now-with-html-email-support-and-web-links/

Hope it helps!

Comment: I do not have Domino installed.  Does this create a problem?  I cannot seem to get a file to attach no matter what I try.

Answer (score 0):

This seems a more relevant portion of code for creating mails in Notes: [send email to a specific Lotus Notes contacts using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25934183/send-email-to-a-specific-lotus-notes-contacts-using-vba)

Do you want your mails opened on the screen before you send them, or can they be sent unseen?

UPDATE: Suggested code

```
subject = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2")
Debug.Print subject

Set NSession = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
Set NUIWorkSpace = CreateObject("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace")
Set NDatabase = NSession.GetDatabase("", "")
If Not NDatabase.IsOpen Then NDatabase.OPENMAIL

For all email-addresses
    EmailAddress = Worksheets("Sheet1").Application.Transpose(Range("A2").Resize(Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value)
    Set NDoc = NDatabase.CreateDocument

    With NDoc
        .Form= "Memo" ' or .ReplaceItemValue("Form", "Memo")
        .SendTo = EmailAddress
        .subject = subject
    End With
    set rtitem= NDoc.CreateRichTextItem("Body")
    Call rt.AppendText(Worksheets("sheet1").Range("d2") & vbLf & vbLf)
    Call rt.EmbedObject(1454, "", "c:filepath.doc")
    Call NDoc.Save(True, False)
Next ' email-address
```

To be handled: Looping, filenames, addresses...

Comment: Initially I would want to open them on screen or in drafts folders as I am sending out sensitive information and I want to make sure I'm sending the right attachments to the right vendors.

Comment: I should also mention because this is a corporate email account we do not have Lotus Notes Domino or Print Merger which is why I'm having to go at it like this.  I'm not a coder but I'm the only person in the office that will even attempt VBA so I'm doing the best I can with no training.

Comment: You can indeed open one mail on screen, or two, or three, at the same time, but I think it isn't really doable when you send 100 mails or so. So you'd have to create and show them one by one, and then approve them. Save as draft might be a better possibility. I modified my answer.

Comment: I updated my code above.  @For all emai-addresses i get an error that says its expecting an "="?

Comment: Eh, of course, it is not a valid VBA statement. I don't know too much of VBA in Excel to provide you with the code, so I left it up to you. That line is just pseudo-code... Ditto for the Next-statement the block ends with. Hence the "To be handled: Looping, filenames, addresses..."